# Javascript binary animation infinite loop

Tags: javascript

I have made a binary animation script which is activated by a button click.

Using the current code you can click multiple times and it will stop after each itteration. However, when I tried to refactor the code (currently commented out below), it works fine with one click, but does not stop looping if you click more than once.

Can anyone please help stop the infinite loop, or know of a better way of achieving the same result?

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/rbradshaw/pen/ZEYmjpx

Here is the code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Binary</title>
</head>
<body>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:lang="en" id="binaryarea" width="400px" height="95px">
    <rect id="binarybackground" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <text>
        <tspan x="2" y="15" id="binary"></tspan>
        <tspan x="2" y="30" id="binary"></tspan>
        <tspan x="2" y="45" id="binary"></tspan>
        <tspan x="2" y="60" id="binary"></tspan>
        <tspan x="2" y="75" id="binary"></tspan>
        <tspan x="2" y="90" id="binary"></tspan>
    </text>
  </svg>
  <br><br>
  <button onclick="runBinary()">Click me</button>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
const binary = document.querySelectorAll('#binary');
document.getElementById("binaryarea").addEventListener("load", setBinary);

function runBinary(){
  //uncomment out from here
  // binActions = [];
  // iterations = 10;
  //to here
  iterLength = 20;

  //comment from here
  var binActions1 = setInterval(changeBinary, iterLength);
  var binActions2 = setInterval(changeBinary, iterLength);
  var binActions3 = setInterval(changeBinary, iterLength);
  var binActions4 = setInterval(changeBinary, iterLength);

  setTimeout(() => {
    clearTimeout(binActions1);
    clearTimeout(binActions2);
    clearTimeout(binActions3);
    clearTimeout(binActions4);
  }, 2000)
  //to here

  //uncomment out below from here
//   for(i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
//     binActions[i] = setInterval(changeBinary, iterLength);
//   }   

//   setTimeout(() => {
//     binActions.forEach((_, idx) => {
//       clearTimeout(binActions[idx])
//     })
//   }, 2000)
  //to here
}

function changeBinary() {
  var rec = Math.floor(Math.random() * binary.length);
  var position = Math.floor(Math.random() * binary[0].textContent.length);
  oldtext = binary[rec].textContent;

  if (binary[rec].textContent[position] == "1") {
    newtext = getNewStr(oldtext, position, "0");
    binary[rec].textContent = newtext;
  } else {
      newtext = getNewStr(oldtext, position, "1");
    binary[rec].textContent = newtext;
  }   
}

function getNewStr(string, index, replace) {
  return string.substring(0, index) + replace + string.substring(index + 1);
}

function binaryString(charlen) {
  var str = "";
  for(i = 0; i < charlen; i++) {
      str += Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
  }  
  return str
}

function setBinary() {
  binary.forEach(row => {
    row.textContent = binaryString(45);
  })
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the interval with the old `intervalID` before you start a new interval.

The shortest way is to use global variables for the `intervalID` supplied from [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) and clear the intervals if needed, without having a fixed interval.

Thinkable would be global array of running `intervalId`, like

```
// global
var intervals = [];
```

and a function for clearing all intervals

```
function clearIntervals() {
    intervals.forEach(clearTimeout);
    intervals.length = 0;            // empty array by keeping the object reference
}
```

Then in

```
function runBinary() {
```

clear the old intervals

```
clearIntervals();
```

and add the intervals to `intervals`

```
intervals.push(binActions1, binActions2, binActions3, binActions4);
```

as well as the clearance of the intervals.

```
intervals.push(setTimeout(clearIntervals, 3000));
```

The last one prevent hanging over intervals with a fixed interval.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Nina. I have used this and updated the codepen.
This solves the infinite looping,and is fine with single clicks. however with multiple clicks during the script running, the length of the script on subsequential clicks varies. is there any way to make sure it runs for the set amount of time on each click please?

Comment: do you mean, on click, it should be running longer, eg for every click add 2 seconds?

Comment: yes, on click. it seems to reset the time out on a couple of clicks whilst it is running, but when you click again after it has stopped, its shorter.

Comment: you need to push the clearance interval as well to the `intervals` array. please see edit.

Answer (score 1):

You don't declare `binActions` as a local variable and as such it will be scoped to be global.

The next time you click it will override `binActions` array and your `setTimeout` will clear the new intervals and not the old ones.

Just use `let` or `var` and it should be fixed.

```
var binActions
```